# How to prevent children from getting focus when using keyboard events

Tags: flutter

This question is related to this one
[Widgets inside a closed section still getting the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72979334/widgets-inside-a-closed-section-still-getting-the-focus)

After trying with `!_isOpen` I tried with fixed value `TRUE` :

```
AbsorbPointer( absorbing: `TRUE`, child: content )
```

And I figure that the `AbsorbPointer` handle only the mouse events not the keyboard event, so thats why the Widgets still continue to get the Focus,

So the question is How to stop also the keyboard events `RawKeyboardListener` for the children ?

Comment: Are you getting focus on text fields?

Comment: I ma getting the focus on any widget wrapped with RawKeyboardListener